# Debug errors from my triplet sum from an array code from C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sum, triplet

I was tring a codingninjas problem, while executing got only 1 test case satisfied, please help.

Given a random integer array and a number x. Find and print the triplets of elements in the array which sum to x.

While printing a triplet, print the smallest element first.

That is, if a valid triplet is (6, 5, 10) print "5 6 10". There is no constraint that out of 5 triplets which have to be printed on 1st line. You can print triplets in any order, just be careful about the order of elements in a triplet.

Sample Input

```
7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
12
```

Sample Output

```
1 4 7
1 5 6
2 3 7
2 4 6
3 4 5
```

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void FindTriplet(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n-2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n -1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j+1; k < n; k++)
            {
                if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] == sum)
                {   
                    if(arr[i]<arr[j] && arr[i]<arr[k])
                    {
                        if(arr[j]<arr[k])
                            cout << arr[i] << " "<< arr[j] << " " << arr[k] <<endl;
                        else
                            cout << arr[i] << " "<< arr[k] << " " << arr[j] <<endl;
                    }
                    else if(arr[j]<arr[i] && arr[j]<arr[k])
                    {
                        if(arr[i]<arr[k])
                            cout << arr[j] << " "<< arr[i] << " " << arr[k] <<endl;
                        else
                            cout << arr[j] << " "<< arr[k] << " " << arr[i] <<endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(arr[i]<arr[j])
                            cout << arr[k] << " "<< arr[i] << " " << arr[j] <<endl;
                        else
                            cout << arr[k] << " "<< arr[j] << " " << arr[i] <<endl;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;

    int x;
    cin>>size;
    
    int *input=new int[1+size]; 
    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cin>>input[i];
    cin>>x;

    FindTriplet(input,size,x);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to permute all possible triplets?

Comment: Please show the actual output

Comment: In C++ try and use `std::vector`. Here it's easier to use one and `push_back` with values.

Comment: What kind of error did you get? Is that "Time Limit Exeeded"?

Comment: By the way, why do you allocate `1+size` elements?

Comment: Yes need to permute all possible triplets

Comment: No time limit exeeded error is not the case here unfortunately

Comment: I did not allocate 1+size, the main part is already provided in the question, I just needed to define the function

Comment: Are you sure that the initial array is sorted?

Comment: It can be extremely helpful to construct a test case that produces an incorrect result. Not only does it make it a lot easier to find bugs, it makes it a lot easier to prove that a potential solution really did solve the exposed problem.

Comment: The array is sorted or not, doesn't matters, I gave if else conditions to show the output from smaller to larger

Comment: 70

9 5 7 27 22 21 2 7 10 12 3 26 10 19 18 24 9 30 12 18 12 13 11 18 3 3 12 22 29 19 11 21 29 3 1 9 5 26 29 23 30 27 8 11 12 20 5 28 5 3 11 22 18 24 12 29 25 17 29 18 20 18 25 27 10 5 30 29 5 14 

66

The is one of the test cases which is not being satisfied

Comment: Now that you have a test case, please adjust your `main` program by getting rid of the `cin` statements and placing the data directly into the variables themselves, [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa87540442b71a88).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did that. Instead of removing cin statemts, I gave the inputs as per the test case, it also gave a output which looked to be correct, like the order of the first element to be smallest and and the third element to be largest in output.

I think the problem is when the two elements in the triplet will be equal, becuase I used < instead of <=

Comment: You didn't change `main` as I outlined.  There should be no `cin` statements.  The other way to do this is to put all of that input data into a string and use `std::istringstream` instead of `cin` to read the data.  The bottom line is that you should prepare the code so that the help you get here will just need to take the code, compile it, and run it, all without having to sit at the keyboard typing in data every time the program is run.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie all the test cases have been satisfied, I was correct, I replaced all the < with <= and it satisfied all the test cases.

Comment: Thanks to each and everyone who gave their valuable time in helping me solve this logical error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your posted failed test case `70 9 .... 66` you output `762` triplets, `713` of which are duplicates. I suspect you are not supposed to output duplicates. With `<=` `715` are duplicates.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It was a logical error, I have posted the correct code. The problem was when it had to compare two equal numbers in a single triplet output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would happen if there the triplet consists of 2 equal numbers on the i-th and j-th position, and `arr[k] > arr[i]`? For example `(1, 1, 2)` with the required sum `4`?

The expression `arr[i]<arr[j] && arr[i]<arr[k]` is false. The same is true for `arr[j]<arr[i] && arr[j]<arr[k]`. So you fall into the `else` branch (`arr[k]<arr[i] && arr[k]<arr[j]`), and this is not true.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was thinking and it did solve my error. It was just a logical eror.

Comment: Good eyes Dimitry.

Answer (score 0):

It was a logical error.

I replaced the < with <= to enable the code to compare the equal numbers as well.

The correct code is -

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void FindTriplet(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n-2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n -1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j+1; k < n; k++)
            {
                if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] == sum)
                {   
                    if(arr[i]<=arr[j] && arr[i]<=arr[k])
                    {
                        if(arr[j]<=arr[k])
                            cout << arr[i] << " "<< arr[j] << " " << arr[k] <<endl;
                        else
                            cout << arr[i] << " "<< arr[k] << " " << arr[j] <<endl;
                    }
                    else if(arr[j]<=arr[i] && arr[j]<=arr[k])
                    {
                        if(arr[i]<=arr[k])
                            cout << arr[j] << " "<< arr[i] << " " << arr[k] <<endl;
                        else
                            cout << arr[j] << " "<< arr[k] << " " << arr[i] <<endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(arr[i]<=arr[j])
                            cout << arr[k] << " "<< arr[i] << " " << arr[j] <<endl;
                        else
                            cout << arr[k] << " "<< arr[j] << " " << arr[i] <<endl;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;

    int x;
    cin>>size;
    
    int *input=new int[1+size]; 
    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cin>>input[i];
    cin>>x;

    FindTriplet(input,size,x);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me.